# How to manipulate tinyMCE image functionality

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to manipulate the functionality of tinyMCE when user tries to attach picture in the editor. What I want to achieve is to HARDCODE the properties of the picture. So when he selects a picture I want to disable the options for SIZE selection, orientation and all other options. Is this possible and what are the ways to do that... I searched the web but without any luck. My idea is to open the script file ot tinyMCE image plugin and to change the values which the script takes and inserts like inline styles, but I'll be glad to see if there is more elegant solution.

Thanks in advance,
Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `unselectable=true` attribute to the image. This way the image cannot get resized (you may strip out that attribute later on before saving the content to db). To disallow special attributes of your image you may define what attributes are allowed using the tinymce valid_elements setting.

UPDATE: This is the css necessary to be set using the tinymce param content_css in order to make images non-resizeable

```
img {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Is this attribute working cross browser? Because I succeeded to manipulate the size, float and other things thru content.css by changing the img tag properties... But I'm still facing the problem with the dragging. And also one more interesting problem ... when I import image sometimes the text isn't flowing around it and pushing my image down...

Comment: sry, unselectable is for IE only. see my updated post for the other browsers

Comment: OK what about the text floating around the image ? I've noticed that if I add image when the editor is blank ( no text in the paragraph ) after the image is added the text starts to push the image down... After some tracing I've noticed that the image is added inside the paragraph but if the paragraph is blank and you add image - another paragraph appears into DOM and you're not able to write in that one which will flow the text around your image.

Comment: never encountered this problem before